# Ionic fails to load data on device

Tags: php, android, json, ionic-framework

I have test this ionic code on my browser, it works as expected

services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Penjualan', function($http) {
  var dataArray = $http.get('http://192.168.1.35/test.php');

  return {
    all: function() {
      return dataArray;
    },
    remove: function(data) {
      dataArray.splice(dataArray.indexOf(data), 1);
    },
    get: function(dataId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        if (dataArray[i].sqlrecno === parseInt(dataId)) {
          return dataArray[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

This is the portion of the code inside 192.168.1.35/test.php

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=192.168.1.35';
$user = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
```

My php file returns json which will be used in my ionic project. 192.168.1.35 is my computer ip. It works on my computer, but the app fails to load json data on device.

Comment: Where are you testing this? Emulator or on physical device?

Comment: physical device

Comment: Is your device is on the same network ? And Does the IP is accessible from web browser of the device?

Comment: Yes. I haven't test the web browser on device. I have just tested the app on device.

Comment: Check if you can open the same IP `192.168.1.35` from the web browser of the device.

Comment: No, I can't access it. Actually, my device isn't on the same network. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: So you need get your device on the same network and make sure you can access the IP from that device.